# Adding list object inside a list C#

Tags: c#, python, list

I'm new in c#. I just want to ask if it is possible to insert a list object inside a c# list just like in python? C# addrange only insert multiple item at once but not a list object.

For example:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: You can create a List that contains List's. List<List<int>>

Comment: List<List<int>> = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() {1,2,3}, new List<int>() {4,5,6}, new List<int>() {7,8,9}};

Comment: Yes. Please use the type [`List<List<int>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but is much more verbose than python.

As some comments already answered, you can use a List of List to create something like your python example:

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() {1,2,3}, new List<int>() {4,5,6}, new List<int>() {7,8,9}};
```

You can also make a list of different objects just declaring it a List of Objects:

```
List<object> listOfObjects = new List<object>();
listOfObjects.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }); // Adding list of int
listOfObjects.Add("text"); // Adding string
listOfObjects.Add(new float[] { 1.42f, 51.7f}); // Adding array of float
listOfObjects.AddRange(listOfObjects); // Duplicating all the elements of listOfObjects
listOfObjects.AddRange(listOfLists); // Adding all elments of the list listOfLists
```

List [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a way of adding many elements at once inside a list.